# If else statement in for loop

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Could it be possible to have if else condition with a for loop

E.g.

```
  IF (emp_no IS NULL) then
 for i in (select * from employees where emp_no= p_retval)
else
 for i in (select * from employees where emp_no= p_retval_withcond)
end if;
```

When I tried the above I have got compilation errors.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure is as follows

```
IF (emp_no IS NULL) then
  for i in (select * from employees where emp_no= p_retval)
  loop
    -- loop actions
  end loop;
else
  for i in (select * from employees where emp_no= p_retval_withcond)
  loop
    -- second loop actions
  end loop;
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible with a for loop but if your actions in the loop are similar in the two cases I would do this by cursors.

```
declare
cursor c1 is select * from employees where emp_no= p_retval;
cursor c2 is select * from employees where emp_no= p_retval_withcond;
ligne employees%rowtype;
.....
begin
   IF (emp_no IS NULL) then
      open c1;
   ELSE
      open C2;
   END IF;
   loop
      IF (emp_no IS NULL) then
         fetch C1 into ligne;
         exit when c1%notfound;
      ELSE
         fetch C2 into ligne;
         exit when c2%notfound;
      END IF;
      -- loop actions
      ....  
   end loop;
   IF (emp_no IS NULL) then
      close c1;
   ELSE
      close C2;
   END IF;
end;
```